# How to get client IP address using python bottle framework

Tags: python, bottle

I need client IP address using python. I have tried below code but its not working in server:

```
from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname 
ip = gethostbyname(gethostname()) 
print ip
```

On the server, I get '127.0.0.1' every time. Is there any way to find IP address of the client?

Comment: is there any service in-between, for example nginx that actually receives external connection from client and forwards html request to bottle?

Comment: @LukaRahne I have the same problem indeed when Apache forwards the request to bottle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954669/apache-python-bottle-visitor-ip-always-refers-to-127-0-0-1 Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 16):

You're getting the IP address of your *server*, not of your server's *clients*.

You want to look at *the request's* `REMOTE_ADDR`, like this:

```
from bottle import Bottle, request

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    client_ip = request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ['Your IP is: {}\n'.format(client_ip)]

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

---

**EDIT #1**: Some folks have observed that, for them, the value of `REMOTE_ADDR` is always the same IP address (usually `127.0.0.1`). This is because they're behind a proxy (or load balancer). In this case, the client's original IP address is typically stored in header `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. The following code will work in either case:

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    client_ip = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') or request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ['Your IP is: {}\n'.format(client_ip)]
```

---

**EDIT #2**: Thanks to @ArtOfWarfare's comment, I learned that `REMOTE_ADDR` is not required per PEP-333. Couple of observations:

- The [CGI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.8) does require `REMOTE_ADDR`:

> The REMOTE_ADDR variable MUST be set to the network address of the client sending the request to the server.

- However, [PEP-333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables) does not explicitly require `HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR`, only going as far as this (emphasis mine):

> A server or gateway **SHOULD** attempt to provide as many other CGI variables as are applicable.

- All of the (admittedly few) web frameworks that I'm familiar with set `HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR`. AFAICT, it's a *de facto* "standard." But technically, YMMV.

Comment: I have the same problem and REMOTE_ADDR always gives 127.0.0.1 : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954669/apache-python-bottle-visitor-ip-always-refers-to-127-0-0-1

Comment: How does this work? Who is setting this variable named `REMOTE_ADDR` and how is it transmitted? Is it set by the client software, or the client hardware, or a router in between, or by wsgi, or who?

Would it make a difference whether this GET request came from an ordinary browser like Firefox or if it came from a Python `requests` script? PEP 333 makes no mention of it, so I'm curious where `REMOTE_ADDR` is specified/standardized/documented?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Thanks, I didn't realize that it wasn't standard. See my edit in response to the points you raise. Happy to reedit for additional clarity if you'd like.

Answer (score 7):

Server might be behind a proxy.  Use this for proxy and forward support:

```
request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') or request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

Comment: Why `or` ? Can you explain, is it a bitwise operator `or` ? Or simply to handle the case HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is `None` ?

Comment: Exactly.  Sometimes, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is None, but is important to check proxied IPs first.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the external IP, you will need to get it from an external source, i.e whatismyip.com or somewhere that offers an api. If that's what you're looking for, take a look at the Requests module http://docs.python-requests.org/

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.  (Or maybe I didn't understand it. :)

Comment: You know what, I did. I saw the code he was attempting to use and jumped to a conclusion. Good eye.