# Client IP when behind AWS network load balancer from Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, sockets, proxy-protocol

When running a socket server behind a network load balancer, with instances specified by IP, ...

```
server_sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
server_sock.setblocking(False)
server_sock.bind(('', port))
server_sock.listen(socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
sock, adddress = await loop.sock_accept(server_sock)
```

... then...

```
print(adddress)
```

prints what appears to be a private IP of the network load balancer itself.

How can I determine the original client IP?

Comment: To get the ip of a client connected via a load balancer, you will want to consult the header or envar  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405812/how-to-get-client-ip-address-using-python-bottle-framework

Comment: @RodrigoM I don't think that is possible if it's a network load balancer... for one thing, the protocol I'm working with isn't HTTP, so HTTP headers aren't involved.

Comment: Ah right missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [Proxy Protocol V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#proxy-protocol), and then write a function to parse the proxy protocol header [which gets sent ahead of incoming data]...

```
import asyncio
import collections
import socket
import struct


PP_V2_SIGNATURE = b'\r\n\r\n\x00\r\nQUIT\n'

PP_V2_COMMANDS = {
    b'\x00': 'LOCAL',
    b'\x01': 'PROXY',
}

PP_V2_VERSIONS = {
    b'\x02': '2',
}

PP_V2_ADDRESS_FAMILIES = {
    b'\x00': 'AF_UNSPEC',
    b'\x01': 'AF_INET',
    b'\x02': 'AF_INET6',
    b'\x03': 'AF_UNIX',
}

PP_V2_PROTOCOLS = {
    b'\x00': 'UNSPEC',
    b'\x01': 'STREAM',
    b'\x02': 'DGRAM',
}

PP_V2_ADDRESS_FORMATS = {
    'AF_INET': '4B4BHH',
    'AF_INET6': '16B16BHH',
    'AF_UNIX': '108B108B',
}

ProxyProtocolV2Header = collections.namedtuple('ProxyProtocolV2Header', [
    'version',
    'command',
    'protocol',
    'address_family',
    'address',
])

ProxyProtocolIpAddress = collections.namedtuple('ProxyProtocolIpAddress', [
    'source_ip',
    'source_port',
    'dest_ip',
    'dest_port',
])


async def proxy_protocol_header_recv(loop, sock):
    # The header, itself has a header
    header_format = '>12sccH'
    header_length = 16

    header_raw = await recv_num_bytes(loop, sock, header_length)
    header_unpacked = struct.unpack(header_format, header_raw)

    signature = header_unpacked[0]
    version_and_command = header_unpacked[1][0]
    protocol_and_address_family = header_unpacked[2][0]
    address_length = header_unpacked[3]

    if signature != PP_V2_SIGNATURE:
        raise Exception('Incorrect proxy protocol signature')

    version = PP_V2_VERSIONS[bytes([version_and_command >> 4])]
    command = PP_V2_COMMANDS[bytes([version_and_command & 0x0f])]

    protocol = PP_V2_PROTOCOLS[bytes([protocol_and_address_family & 0x0f])]
    address_family = PP_V2_ADDRESS_FAMILIES[bytes([protocol_and_address_family >> 4])]

    address_raw = await recv_num_bytes(loop, sock, address_length)

    address_format = PP_V2_ADDRESS_FORMATS[address_family]
    address = struct.unpack(address_format, address_raw[:struct.calcsize(address_format)])

    return ProxyProtocolV2Header(
        version=version,
        command=command,
        protocol=protocol,
        address_family=address_family,
        # For IPV6/Unix, you'll need to do something else
        address=ProxyProtocolIpAddress(
            source_ip='.'.join(str(part) for part in address[:4]),
            source_port=address[8],
            dest_ip='.'.join(str(part) for part in address[4:8]),
            dest_port=address[9],
        ) if address_family == 'AF_INET' else None,
    )

async def recv_num_bytes(loop, sock, num_bytes):
    incoming_buf = bytearray(num_bytes)
    incoming = memoryview(incoming_buf)
    bytes_in_total = 0

    while bytes_in_total != num_bytes:
        bytes_just_in = await loop.sock_recv_into(sock, incoming[bytes_in_total:])
        if bytes_just_in == 0:
            raise Exception('Socket closed')
        bytes_in_total += bytes_just_in

    return incoming_buf
```

... which you you can use as, for example:

```
async def main(loop):

    port = 5023

    server_sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    server_sock.setblocking(False)
    server_sock.bind(('', port))
    server_sock.listen(socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

    while True:
        print('Waiting for connection')
        sock, adddress = await loop.sock_accept(server_sock)
        header = await proxy_protocol_header_recv(loop, sock)
        print(header.address.source_ip)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Answer (score 1):

> *with instances specified by IP*

...you can't.

With instances (targets) specified by IP, Network Load Balancer doesn't have the ability to hook sufficiently deeply into the network infrastructure to preserve the client IP.  When you specify instances by instance ID, the client IP is automatically preserved.

> You can configure a target group so that you register targets by instance ID or IP address. If you specify targets using an instance ID, the source IP addresses of the clients are preserved and provided to your applications. If you specify targets by IP address, the source IP addresses are the private IP addresses of the load balancer nodes.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS load balancers place the client ip into the 'X-Forwarded-For' header
so simple query it by:

```
class CustomHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
...
  def do_GET(self):
    aws_forwarded_ip = self.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For')
...
```

Comment: I think this is true for application load balancers, but I don't think for network load balancers. For one thing, in my case, HTTP isn't the protocol used, so there aren't any HTTP headers to add to.