# How to get the real client IP in Delphi for the Proxy Protocol V2 enabled load balancer or full proxy server

Tags: delphi, reverse-proxy, delphi-10.3-rio, amazon-elb

There is a sample Python code in one of the answers of this [Client IP when behind AWS network load balancer from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53144461/client-ip-when-behind-aws-network-load-balancer-from-python)

Appreciate if someone will translate the python codes in Delphi using Synapse socket or any socket components.

If there is a better solution using Delphi then that is most welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing or translation service. 
 We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself 
 and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, 
 include the relevant portions of your code (and any original code) in the form of a 
 [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
 and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: For which OS do you want the translation? Delphi supports a number of OS: Windows, Linux, iOS, MacOS, Android. Python code look like basic socket API.

Comment: Sorry for that translation request... there was also no feedback if the specified python codes would work.

Comment: The OS is Windows.